# SQL Error Alter Table?

Tags: sql, alter-table

I have been trying to add columns to a table using some logic that produces this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Master_List 
  ADD COLUMN Service VARCHAR(100) , 
             Vendor VARCHAR(100) , 
             Product VARCHAR(100) , 
             Service_Description VARCHAR(100) , 
             Level/Scale VARCHAR(100) , 
             SunGard_Contract_Schedule_ID VARCHAR(100) , 
             Application_Owner VARCHAR(100) , 
             Application_Servers VARCHAR(100) , 
             Required_Support/Dependencies VARCHAR(100);
```

whenever I have been trying to run it I continually get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in field definition.
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:338)
>       at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:288)
>       at Testing.main(Testing.java:54)

I have been checking online for the proper format for the ALTER TABLE command, and the formatting seems to be correct, I have tried changing so many things I have run out of ideas of how to fix it....

The table name is Master_List, and none of those columns already exist inside it.

This is being used inside Java, incase that is relevant.

Comment: What RDBMS? If SQL Server you can use [Required_Support/Dependencies] if you really want that character in a column name. (It's easier not to though so you don't have to keep using the square bracket syntax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be the `/` in your column names that is giving you the problem

Comment: Thanks, seems that was it. Still new to SQL and unsure what kind of things can be inside column names. Figured since _ was alright that / would be fine too. Thanks!

Comment: You can accept this as the correct answer by clicking the tick beside it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your column names contain the "/" character, and that is not a valid character for column names.